# Player climbing wall issue

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

Basically what i want, is when my player is falling off and is close to a wall, he can jump and climb it, and also he can jump and move on the X' axis in the oposite direction of the wall. So i made 3 groundCheck game objects as childs of my player Transform, and they are set below him, one in the bottom center, one in the bottom left and one in the bottom right. Then i check if hes colliding with the walls, the ground with these functions :

```
   bool CheckDown()
      {
   if (Physics2D.OverlapCircle(groundCheck.position, 0.01f, whatIsGround))
           return true;
       else
           return false;
     }

   bool CheckGround()
   {


       if (Physics2D.OverlapCircle(groundCheck.position, 0.01f, whatIsGround))
           return true;
       if (Physics2D.OverlapCircle(groundCheck2.position, 0.01f, whatIsGround))
           return true;

       if (Physics2D.OverlapCircle(groundCheck3.position, 0.01f, whatIsGround))
           return true;
       else
           return false;
   }
   bool CheckWallLeft()
   {
       if (Physics2D.OverlapCircle(groundCheck3.position, 0.01f, whatIsGround))
           return true;


       else
           return false;
   }
   bool CheckWallRight()
   {
       if (Physics2D.OverlapCircle(groundCheck2.position, 0.01f, whatIsGround))
           return true;

       else
           return false;
   }
```

then i use these booleans to determine if the player can jump or not :

```
        if (CheckWallLeft() && !CheckWallRight())
        {                
            if (h > 0)
   GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = new Vector2(h * speedHeight,   GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity.y);
        }
        if (!CheckWallLeft() && CheckWallRight())
        {               
            if (h < 0)
            {

                GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = new Vector2(h * speedHeight, GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity.y);
            }
        }   
        if(!CheckGround())
        GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = new Vector2(h * speedHeight, GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity.y);
        if (CheckDown()) {
            GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = new Vector2(h * speedHeight, GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity.y); 
    }
```

H is input getAxis horizontal. But for some reason it only works when hes falling and facing a wall on his left........on the right hes able to move on the X'axis to the wall direction, so he wont fall if he keeps pressing D. Any ideas?

Comment: you are not changing velocity in y direction. how are you trying to achieve jumping and climbing without that?

Comment: with this if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && grounded)
                GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = new Vector2(GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity.x, jumpHeight);

Comment: why no simply use triggers to detect zone near walls and allow jumping there like if your player is in area of trigger of a wall, it can jump. where as you are controlling your horizontal movement by axis input already.